# How to add border in OpenLayers map popup in drupal

Tags: drupal, openlayers

Hi I have to add a border in an OpenLayers popup. I have searched for this but didn't find any article about it. However I did find a function to add a border but I didn't know how to use the function (like `setBorder:function()`) in the drupal module file openlayer.js.
I think it would be easy if I was using OpenLayers API but here I am using a drupal module for OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayer popups consist of HTML so they have CSS styles.

Just **override the css style for the popup class/id**.

Alternatively you can use your own openlayers theme. Copy the '/modules/openlayers/themes/default_dark' folder and make your own theme.

[image]